# How to get respond (status) code from get request?

Tags: java, android, networking

Hi I am using this library:

https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

and I cant find how to get status code from GET request from example.
I dont know if there is some documentation I am missing but anyways I would really appreciate if someone can tell me how to do that.

Comment: The response status isn't in the request. It's in the response. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example code found in the repo `Fast-Android-Networking`. This is a `GET` request which uses `getAsJSONArray` & specify a `JSONArrayRequestListener` to it.

In `JSONArrayRequestListener`, when `onResponse` is called, most probably indicate HTTP status code is `200 OK`. For any error condition, `onError` is called. You can get error code with `error.getErrorCode()`.

```
AndroidNetworking.get(ApiEndPoint.BASE_URL + ApiEndPoint.GET_JSON_ARRAY)
    .setTag(this)
    .addPathParameter("pageNumber", "0")
    .addQueryParameter("limit", "3")
    .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
    .build()
    .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse array : " + response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError error) {
            if (error.getErrorCode() != 0) {
                // received ANError from server
                // error.getErrorCode() - the ANError code from server
                // error.getErrorBody() - the ANError body from server
                // error.getErrorDetail() - just a ANError detail
                Log.d(TAG, "onError errorCode : " + error.getErrorCode());
                Log.d(TAG, "onError errorBody : " + error.getErrorBody());
                Log.d(TAG, "onError errorDetail : " + error.getErrorDetail());
            } else {
                // error.getErrorDetail() : connectionError, parseError, requestCancelledError
                Log.d(TAG, "onError errorDetail : " + error.getErrorDetail());
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this help, good luck!

Comment: `onResponse` is also called for a `201` and a `204`. So 'probably `200`' isn't great. Does anyone know how to get the actual code from a 'good' response?